# WSO2 api manager SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I faced with following exception in WSO2 api manager

```
SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated exception
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cert of the backend ep should be added to the truststore.

Comment: I added but, It's not valid certificate, What I have to do ?

Comment: Is your cert is a valid one ? What is the java version you are using ?

Comment: It's self signed certificate and java version is 1.8.43